# Unable to see the created scaffold code in grails application

Tags: grails

```
I have a domain class which is

class Person{
int age
String firstName
String lastName
}

and I have a controller class which is person controller

class PersonController{
static scaffold=true
...
}
```

the scaffold=true should create all the crud operations with all its views but I am unable to see the created code in my application and I did not find any view pages under sampleapplication->views->person.but when I run the application its working fine. but I want see the created code as well as created view files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static scaffold=true
```

Creates the views and controllers during runtime.

If you want to see the code you have to use this command:

```
grails generate-all Person
```

Read more here:

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/scaffolding.html